# How to clear search conditions and word after a search using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

**Scenario**

I have a userform whereby a button on it doing search function with MatchCase = True in addition to other automated works. Whenever this userform is active and I try to do some search in other opened worbooks, always Match Case is ticked. Everytime I need to manually uncheck the Match case in excel while this userform is active. Please see the pictures

**When userform is not showing**

[image]

**When userform is showing**

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way that I can run my macro with MatchCase = True but at the same time when I open other workbooks and press Ctrl+F Matchcase by default unchecked? In other words how to remove the search keyword and search condition after a search macro execution? I am using the following search codes with search word as a variable `worD`

```
Selection.Find(What:=worD, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Comment: why not do a dummy find operation for anything (asterisk)  with matchcase:=false (and any others you want remembered)? as you've noticed, some find arguments are 'remembered' from last use.

Comment: For the userform, I must do the exact search with `Match case = True` as well as `LookAt:= xlWhole`. The problem is, users still need to manually able to open other excel workbooks and search without the exact search. With the current situation, since macro is doing a case sensitive search, other workbooks which are opened after the execution also by default showing match case true with search history

Comment: @Jeeped There are many search ongoing. Adding dummy search function everytime will increase the macro runtime too. So I am looking for some solution without doing dummy searches again

Comment: But it seems thta's the only [way](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008802_Changing_Default_Search_Settings.html)

Comment: There is none. Certain Range.Find arguments are remembered from last use. Without a dummy Find operation, you could only close excel and reopen it.

Comment: Also described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/find-replace-default-options/4fcfabc2-46fe-4eec-b6cf-749ad3b73144?db=5) _if you do an Edit|Find and change anything, then those changed settings will
be remembered._  Also [here](https://superuser.com/questions/156637/how-do-i-set-search-option-defaults-in-ms-excel-2007) and this seems to be valid for 2016/Excel 365 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute a Dummy-Search when you're done

```
Sub clearFind(ws As Worksheet)
    With ws.Cells
        .Find What:="", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
              SearchFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory maybe you can use SendKeys but in my experience it is NOT RELIABLE.

```
 ' here set a variable to search. After that:
      Application.SendKeys ("^f")
      Application.SendKeys ("{DELETE}")
 ' and finally paste variable.value via SendKeys
```

Answer (score 0):

As per some members here in stack overflow, a simple approach is the dummy search which clear away match case and search history.

```
Sub dummySearch()
    dummy = Cells.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
End Sub
```